# How to mirror front camera

Tags: pyqt, camera, qml

I'm working on a camera project with Qml in my laptop

I used some help from [qml camera](https://doc.qt.io/archives/qt-5.11/qtmultimedia-multimedia-declarative-camera-declarative-camera-qml.html) available in qt qml examples.

Here is my code:

```
import QtQuick 2.12
import QtMultimedia 5.4
import QtQuick.Controls 2.12

Item {
anchors.fill:parent

onVisibleChanged: {
    if(!visible){
        camera.stop()
    }
}

Rectangle {
    id : cameraUI
    anchors.fill: parent
    color:"transparent"

    Camera {
        id: camera

        captureMode: Camera.CaptureVideo

        videoRecorder {
             resolution: "1280x720"
             frameRate: 60
        }
    }

    VideoOutput {
        id: viewFinder
        anchors.fill : parent
        source: camera
    }
}
}
```

i did try to make camera mirrored but I could not figured it out.

**I tried:**

1. format.setScanLineDirection (QVideoSurfaceFormat:: BottomToTop); [link](https://www.qtcentre.org/threads/69415-Flip-Mirror-QCameraViewFinder)
2. transform: Scale{ xScale: -1 } for VideoOutput [link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/53691351/applying-a-mirror-transformation-to-flip-reflect-a-qml-control)
3. (360 - camera.orientation) % 360; for orientation of VideoOutput [link](https://gitlab.com/ubports/apps/camera-app/blob/master/ViewFinderView.qml)

And searched a lot but no clue.

Comment: In its doc writes : [position enumeration](https://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qml-qtmultimedia-camera.html#position-prop) `Camera.FrontFace` ,`The camera is on the front face of the system hardware. For example, on a mobile device, it means it is on the same side as the screen. Viewfinder frames of front-facing cameras are mirrored horizontally, so the users can see themselves as looking into a mirror. Captured images or videos are not mirrored`

Comment: yes, i read that . so is this Inevitable? no way to fix this ?

Comment: @mohsen Your question is unclear, do you want to get the image of the front camera of a mobile? Or do you want to get the image of your webcam mirrored? Or do you want the images of the camera to be saved by applying a mirror?

Comment: real time showing image of webcam

Comment: @mohsen use `transform: Matrix4x4 {
                matrix: Qt.matrix4x4(-1, 0, 0, width, 0, 1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1)
            }`